# undefined method `javascript_dialog' in Watir 2.0.4

Tags: watir

I am not able to click on a java script alert using watir 2.0.4. This is the alert that i am trying to click on. And the line of the code that i am using to click on the javascript alert is

```
browser.javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

All i get is the error message

```
undefined method `javascript_dialog' for #<Watir::IE:0x46efcb8> (NoMethodError)
```

[image]

Do i need to install some specific gems for it to work? I thought watir is all i need and i have it already installed. Is it not supported with Watir 2.0.4 ? Please find my gems below.

I also tried supressing the java scrit alert by adding the following lines before clicking on the javascript alert. It did n't work either. Waiting for your valuable input. Thanks!

```
browser.execute_script "window.confirm = function() { return true; }" 

browser.execute_script "window.alert = function() { return true; }" 

browser.execute_script "window.prompt = function() { return true; }"
```

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

builder (3.0.0)

commonwatir (2.0.4)

ffi (1.0.10 x86-mingw32)

hoe (2.12.3)

minitest (1.6.0)

nokogiri (1.5.0 x86-mingw32)

rake (0.8.7)

rautomation (0.6.3)

rdoc (2.5.8)

s4t-utils (1.0.4)

user-choices (1.1.6.1)

watir (2.0.4)

win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)

win32-process (0.6.5)

windows-api (0.4.0)

windows-pr (1.2.1)

xml-simple (1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

The Watir [RDoc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir/frames) list of methods does not have `.javascript_dialog` listed.

It does however have `.java_dialog_window`

I would try using

```
browser.javascript_dialog_window.button('OK').click
```

I'm not sure if the method got renamed for some reason and the popup page in the wiki did not get updated, or if that page has had the wrong method name all along.   Let me know if this works and if so I can bug TPTB to figure out what needs to get changed.

Comment: No Luck Chuck Van. I tried browser.javascript_dialog_window.button('OK').click  I am getting the error "undefined method `javascript_dialog_window' for #<Watir::IE:0x15f8070> (NoMethodError)"

Comment: what does your require watir line look like, are you specifying any options such as for the use of the Autoit adaptor instead of RAutomation?

Comment: Hi Chuck van, I am not using autoit adaptor or Rautomation. I thought "browser.javascript_dialog_window.button('OK').click" should work without requiring autoit. At the top of my file i just have "require watir". Do i need to require something more?  I know that i can get it working using following lines of autoit code. The reason behind using "browser.javascript_dialog_window.button('OK').click" is, i don't want to use autouit as it does not work consistently all the times. @autoit = WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control');@autoit.WinWaitActive("Message from webpage","");@autoit.Send("{Space}")

Comment: I believe (if you check the source) that command uses RAutomation under the hood,  hence my question if it was set to a specific adaptor.  If you have not set anything it would be using the default.  However it's strange to me that you don't see that method present..   I'm looking at the source right now (on my system it's dialog.rb found in C:\Rubies\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\watir-2.0.4\lib\watir\dialogs ) the method is defined, along with aliases for :dialog and :javascript_dialog.

Comment: Hey.. In my machine under "C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\watir-2.0.4\lib\watir\dialogs" i see only file_field.rb and javascript.rb. I don't see dialog.rb here. I even tried "gem uninstall watir" and then "gem install watir -v 2.0.4". Even then i see only file_field.rb and javascript.rb. I don't understand why dialog.rb file is missing on my machine. How can i get dialog.rb?

Comment: One interesting thing (for me atleast :)). I see "javascript_dialog_window" and "javascript_dialog(opts={})" functions inside "javascript.rb" file. Is it of any help?

Comment: I think I mispoke, this stuff is in javascript.rb  I think I was looking at the directory name when I typed in the file-name (incorrectly)..   So it does look like you have the right file...   OK next question.. I've seen sometimes (due to some of the security stuff in IE) where when changing pages it will actually close the current tab, and open a new one with a different security context, it's transparent to the user, but can cause watir to lose it's connection to the browser,  At the point that dialog comes up, can you do something basic like browser.title or does that fail also?